# Return the maximum value in dictionary with multiple keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary of images with its width and height and I want to sort them based on their width or just find the maximum width among dictionary values.
Thanks for your help.

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image 

folder_images = "data/train/melanoma"
size_images = dict()

for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(folder_images):
    for path_image in filenames:
        image = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, path_image))
        with Image.open(image) as img:
            width, heigth = img.size
            size_images[path_image] = {'width': width, 'heigth': heigth}

for k, v in size_images.items():
    print (k, '-->', v)
```

Output:

```
ISIC_0011130.jpg --> {'width': 1024, 'heigth': 768}
ISIC_0013581.jpg --> {'width': 4288, 'heigth': 2848}
ISIC_0013832.jpg --> {'width': 3008, 'heigth': 2000}
ISIC_0014127.jpg --> {'width': 4288, 'heigth': 2848}
ISIC_0013861.jpg --> {'width': 4288, 'heigth': 2848}
ISIC_0000169.jpg --> {'width': 722, 'heigth': 542}
ISIC_0001140.jpg --> {'width': 1936, 'heigth': 1936}
```

Comment: [**Sorting Mini-HOW TO**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a new dict that has the desired order, you can create an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the result of sorting the original dict's items. [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) stores its items in the order in which they were inserted (whereas the built-in dict which has no internal ordering).

```
from collections import OrderedDict

newDict = OrderedDict(sorted(oldDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['width']))
largest = list(newDict.items())[-1]
# {'ISIC_0013861.jpg', {'width': 4288, 'heigth': 2848})
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the images in ascending height order:

```
for k, v in sorted(size_images.items(), lambda kv: kv[1]['height']):
    print (k, '-->', v)
```

Comment: TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function. I've changed the code to for k, v in sorted(size_images.items(),key= lambda kv: kv[1]['heigth']):
    print (k, '-->', v) and it works great. thanks

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry about that. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Maximum width**

Using `max` with a generator expression:

```
max_width = max(v['width'] for v in size_images.values()}
```

**Sorted by width**

Using `sorted` with a custom key:

```
sorted_list = sorted(sizes_images.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['width'])
```

Note that this will output a list of tuples, sorted by width smallest first. Add `reverse=True` to start with the largest.

Comment: sorted list code is working great however max() function gives me this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @SarahK, Ah, see update. We only need to iterate `dict.values` here, assuming your values are dictionaries.